# Find users who did not re-subscribe

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-range

I have a table Subscriptions in PostgreSQL 10.5:

```
id  user_id  starts_at  ends_at
--------------------------------
1   233      02/04/19   03/03/19
2   233      03/04/19   04/03/19
3   296      02/09/19   03/08/19
4   126      02/01/19   02/28/19
5   126      03/01/19   03/31/19
6   922      02/22/19   03/22/19
7   111      01/22/19   02/21/19
8   111      02/22/19   03/21/19
```

I'd like to get a list of user ids who did not re-subscribe in march. Given the data above, it should show:

```
user_id
-------
296
922
```

How would I go about calculating this. I've given a few queries a try, but they don't work and aren't worth posting

Comment: My tidbit: using `FORMAT(DATE, MM)` to get the month by itself. Then you can compare whether or not `starts_at` was in March, if that's what your question means.

Comment: how would a query on the above data return user_id 295 when it's not present in the dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of not exists and don't get the customers who have start date of March.

```
with cte as 
(
select 1  as ID,   233 as User_Id, '02/04/2019' as Startsat   , '03/03/2019' ends_at union all 
select 2  as ID,   233 as User_Id, '03/04/2019' as Startsat   , '04/03/2019' ends_at union all 
select 3  as ID,   296 as User_Id, '02/09/2019' as Startsat   , '03/08/2019' ends_at union all 
select 4  as ID,   126 as User_Id, '02/01/2019' as Startsat   , '02/28/2019' ends_at union all 
select 5  as ID,   126 as User_Id, '03/01/2019' as Startsat   , '03/31/2019' ends_at union all 
select 6  as ID,   922 as User_Id, '02/22/2019' as Startsat   , '03/22/2019' ends_at)

select *  from cte  c 
where  not exists
(select 1 from cte c1 where c.User_Id = c1.User_Id and date_part('Month',to_date(c1.Startsat,'MM/DD/YYYY'))= '3' )
```

Output:

```
id  user_id startsat    ends_at
3   296 02/09/2019  03/08/2019
6   922 02/22/2019  03/22/2019
```

Here is the fiddle link:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=84e24cd517fa0810bef011d6fb1b2be2

Comment: I incorrectly asked this question, and re-asked it in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55618271/find-subscribers-who-did-not-resubscribe-within-threshold-of-old-subscription - Based on how I originally asked the question, this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you want a specific March, not March of any year.  So:

```
select s.userId
from subscriptions s
group by s.userId
having count(*) filter (where startsAt >= '2019-03-01' and startsAt < '2019-04-01') = 0;
```

You can use `not exists` as well.  This works better if you have a list of users:

```
select u.*
from users u
where not exists (select 1
                  from subscriptions s
                  where s.userid = u.userid and
                        s.startsAt >= '2019-03-01' and
                        s.startsAt < '2019-04-01'
                 );
```

Instead of `users`, you can also use:

```
select distinct s.userId
from subscriptions
where . . .
```

Comment: This doesn't necessarily work, as our users table contains users who have never subscribed, so we only want to look at users who were subscribed in Feb, but did not renew in March.

Comment: @theartofbeing . . . I don't see any condition on February whatsoever in your question.  That is not hard to add, but there is none.

Comment: I thought that was implied by asking for users who resubscribed in march, apologies.

Comment: I incorrectly asked this question, and re-asked it in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55618271/find-subscribers-who-did-not-resubscribe-within-threshold-of-old-subscription - Based on how I originally asked the question, this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, here a re a couple of other options:

## Option 1

You can create 2 CTEs, one for each month (assuming you're looking at particular months, and not just February/March in general). Note that this uses the [range](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/rangetypes.html) data type to filter the dates.

```
WITH 
    -- sample data
    Subscriptions("id", user_id, starts_at, ends_at) AS
    (
        VALUES
        (1,   233,      DATE'02/04/19',   DATE'03/03/19'),
        (2,   233,      DATE'03/04/19',   DATE'04/03/19'),
        (3,   296,      DATE'02/09/19',   DATE'03/08/19'),
        (4,   126,      DATE'02/01/19',   DATE'02/28/19'),
        (5,   126,      DATE'03/01/19',   DATE'03/31/19'),
        (6,   922,      DATE'02/22/19',   DATE'03/22/19')
    ),
    -- separate CTEs for February and March data
    -- using range type for easy filter.
    FebruarySubscriptions AS
    (
        SELECT * FROM Subscriptions 
        WHERE daterange('2019-02-01', '2019-03-01') @> starts_at
    ),
    MarchSubscriptions AS
    (
        SELECT * FROM Subscriptions 
        WHERE daterange('2019-03-01', '2019-04-01') @> starts_at
    )
SELECT * 
FROM FebruarySubscriptions
    LEFT JOIN MarchSubscriptions ON
        MarchSubscriptions.user_id = FebruarySubscriptions.user_id
WHERE MarchSubscriptions."id" IS NULL
```

## Option 2

Use `LEAD` window function to figure out which users don't have a re-subscription. The benefit of this option is it's more extensible.

```
WITH 
    Subscriptions("id", user_id, starts_at, ends_at) AS
    (
        VALUES
        (1,   233,      DATE'02/04/19',   DATE'03/03/19'),
        (2,   233,      DATE'03/04/19',   DATE'04/03/19'),
        (3,   296,      DATE'02/09/19',   DATE'03/08/19'),
        (4,   126,      DATE'02/01/19',   DATE'02/28/19'),
        (5,   126,      DATE'03/01/19',   DATE'03/31/19'),
        (6,   922,      DATE'02/22/19',   DATE'03/22/19')
    ),
    Resubscriptions(user_id, current_subscription, next_subscription) AS
    (
        SELECT 
            user_id, 
            starts_at, 
            LEAD(starts_at) OVER
            (
                PARTITION BY user_id
                ORDER BY starts_at ASC
            )
        FROM Subscriptions
    )
SELECT * 
FROM Resubscriptions
WHERE 
    daterange('2019-02-01', '2019-03-01') @> current_subscription
    AND next_subscription IS NULL
```